# how to add text label instead of dot in calendar when we want to add event

Tags: android

I am using `material design calendar` in android I want to add text instead of dot to show the event it only provides dot span I have made custom text span to show the text but it overlaps all the text on that date.

//here I am adding decorator to calendar

```
 List<HighlightDates> highlightDates = new ArrayList<>();
                int i=0;
                for(CalendarDay day : calendarDays){
                    HighlightDates highlightDate = new HighlightDates(calendarDays, context, list.get(i));
                    highlightDates.add(highlightDate);
                    calendar.addDecorator(highlightDate);
                    i++;
                }


//here is event class to show text on that date

        public class HighlightDates implements DayViewDecorator {
            private Context context;
            Object value;
            List<CalendarDay> dayList;


            public HighlightDates(List<CalendarDay> day, Context context, Object value) {
                this.context = context;
                this.value=value;
                this.dayList=day;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
                return dayList.contains(day);
            }

            @Override
            public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
              //  view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
                view.addSpan(new DotSpan(String.valueOf(value)));
            }
        }

//here my custom method to add text below the date instead of dot

     public  DotSpan(String value){
            this.value=value;

        }

        @Override
        public void drawBackground(
                Canvas canvas, Paint paint,
                int left, int right, int top, int baseline, int bottom,
                CharSequence charSequence,
                int start, int end, int lineNum
        ) {
            int oldColor = paint.getColor();
            if (color != 0) {
                paint.setColor(color);
            }
            canvas.drawCircle((left + right) / 2, bottom + radius, radius, paint);
            paint.setColor(oldColor);
            Paint white = new Paint();
            white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawRect(left,top,right,bottom, white);
            canvas.drawText(value,left+right/4,top+bottom/2, paint);

        }
```